# Load and animate 3D model (.fbx format) in Swift 5

Tags: swift, 3d, fbx

What is the most elegant and easy way to load and animate .fbx models in Swift 5?

Is this even possible for a simple iOS App?

As far as I know there is ARKit but I don’t want any augmented reality. Just a 3D model inside of my UIView of the format .fbx.